# Rails 3.1.rc1 and accept_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have the following models:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :survey_id # I'm using external DB
  belongs_to :user #UPDATED
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  accept_nested_attributes_for :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :question_id # I'm using external DB
  belogns_to :survey
end
```

If I go to rails console and save a model:

```
>> params = {"title"=>"Survey 1", "questions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"title"=>"Question 2"}}}
>> survey = User.first.surveys.build(params) #UPDATED
>> survey.questions.size
=> 2
>> survey = User.first.surveys.new(params)
>> survey.questions.size
=> 1
```

Rails is duplicating question resource on surveys. Maybe is it a Rails 3.1 bug? The code is similiar to railscasts episode 197.

Comment: Ok, the problem is in the `build` function because using `new` it works well.

Comment: Sorry, I do some changes to the code because the original code is quite different.

Comment: The method is actually 'accepts_nested_attributes_for'.

Comment: ...and belogns_to should obviously be belongs_to.

(it might help other n00bs like me if you corrected the code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was fixed in [this commit.](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/67f5c076de75cf61babff7f59eadae87599a9a2d)

The fix is present Rails 3.1.0rc2, so if you update your Rails version in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.0.rc2'
```

And run

```
$ bundle update rails
```

It should work as expected.